# Rule for writing superscript in text mode

Tags: math-mode, formatting, superscripts, text-mode

In the scope of gaining space, I would like my superscript minuses to be shortened from:

```
$ J^{-1} $
```

to

```
$ J^{\text -1} $
```

using a rule.

Comment: What do you mean by "using a rule"?

Comment: @JouleV I believe a hyphen is meant.@Dash: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry but I don’t quite understand. You wanna shorten a short sequence of characters to a long sequence?

Comment: What I mean by a rule is that I don't want a solution that consists in putting "\text" in every brackets like I did. Instead, I would like a a way to define it globally.
In the spirit of defining a "newcommand" perhaps.
If you run my code, you'll see that the second proposition has a shorter superscript "-1". It therefore uses less space which is my final goal. I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: @Dash [**DON'T DO THAT!!!**](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2126). Your readers will be grateful.

Comment: @Dash Well, now I understand your question. That's not the right symbol anyway, though ... But we do have ways if you insist to do that.

Comment: Wow I did not know it was polemic. Don't worry, I want to do that for a small text, I think I will even forget the idea after all. Can I upvote comments ?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that “saving space” at the expense of readability should be pursued.

In the picture, top is the standard, bottom is the “space saving” version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\shortminus}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\short@minus\relax}}
\newcommand{\short@minus}[2]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \std@minus
  \else
    \ifx#1\textstyle
      \std@minus
    \else
      \scalebox{0.5}[1]{$\m@th#1\std@minus$}%
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begingroup\lccode`~=`-\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\shortminus
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`-="8000 }

\begin{document}

$-J^{\csname std@minus\endcsname1}$

$-J^{-1}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think I will not pursue this idea after all. But thanks for the code anyway, it helps me understanding the "makeatletter/makeatother" stuff. 
I am surprised you think it looks less readable. Of course the symbol is smaller, but it looks more like the way I (and possibly others) write on paper. The minus symbol is still visible and the reader should think about an "inverse". And because I insisted on the definition of $J^{-1}$ at the beginning of the text.
I don't think this should be read from 100 feet using binoculars and I can read it with myopia. Can you develop your comment ?

Comment: @Dash If you want that the inverse is denoted differently, it's better to define a command for it, and not monkeying with the minus sign generally.

Comment: Why are general modifications of such sign a bad idea ?

Comment: @Dash Try `$a^{m-n}$`.